# Cloud Build: How to restrict when to build depending if a directory got modified?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, continuous-integration

I have a Cloud Build in GCP that pulls from github and builds images when a PR merges to master. However I would like to restrict builds to occur only when a particular folder gets modified. There is a similar functionality in TeamCity by specifying Trigger Rules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Included files` trigger setting does allow you to specify which files trigger a build. It does support globbing, patterns such as directory/* to trigger on changes to specific directory. Here is a snippet from the [cloud build documentation](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/running-builds/create-manage-triggers) -

`Included files (optional): Changes to these files will trigger a build. You can use glob strings to specify multiple files with wildcard characters. Acceptable wildcard characters include the characters supported by Go Match, **, and alternation`